# Find procedures referencing a column and not another column containing the same name?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

There are many methods here for finding all stored procedures in SQL Server containing some specified text but I'd like something a bit different.

Suppose I want to find all procedures referencing the column named `defg`, but I don't want that procedure listed if it references only column `abcdefg`. If it contains both then I want it, but if it only contains `abcdefg` then it doesn't reference column `defg` so I am not interested in it.

Comment: This will not be easy, what if the character left from "defg" is a space, or a tab, or a return, or a dot, or .... And then the same thing for the character after "defg"

Comment: This sounds like basic set intersection logic, depending on your naming conventions this could be just a case of finding which column names exist in the procedure denitinion, grouping by object_id and filtering.

Comment: Thanks @Stu, sounds like a promising approach.

Comment: @Dale K, I had tried nothing because I couldn't think of where to start. I could only think of inspecting all procedures containing defg knowing that some of them would contain only abcdefg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE     @ColName sysname = 'MyTable.defg'

SELECT      OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS stored_proc, is_selected, is_updated, is_select_all
FROM        sys.sql_dependencies
WHERE       OBJECT_NAME(referenced_major_id) = PARSENAME(@ColName, 2)
            AND COL_NAME(referenced_major_id, referenced_minor_id) = PARSENAME(@ColName, 1)
            AND OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id, 'BaseType') = 'P'
ORDER BY    1
```

This might miss stored procedures which use deferred name resolution on queries that reference your column e.g. if you create temp tables in a stored procedure and then JOIN some of these tables with your base table the stored procedure will use deferred name resolution and your base table + column might not end up in `sys.sql_dependencies` so the query above will miss the stored procedure.